# Best way to modify downstream references to a code workbook dataset to point to the new code repository dataset created using helper?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

When using the "Export to Code Repository Helper" tool in an existing code workbook, what is the most efficient way to modify downstream dependencies to point to the newly created Code Repository dataset?

We want to modify all downstream dependencies, not a subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to replace the *logic* of the original source dataset, without changing the *actual dataset* (i.e. by keeping the dataset with existing RID.) You can do it by:

1. Removing the job spec of the dataset (dataset view -> details -> Job Spec -> edit -> delete)
2. Setting the output of your code in repository to be the existing dataset.

This way you do not have to modify any downstream dependencies.